# Fetch the integer value of badge(from push notification) : Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification, badge

In one of my apps, I want to fetch the integer value of badge(from push notification) programmatically.

`edit:` Inside 'application didReceiveRemoteNotification', I have to set:

```
badge No. = existing badge No. + 1.
```

And, how to find this `existing badge No.`? Can anyone help...?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
```

is that what you looking for?

for the badge number in APN just arrived.

in `AppDelegate`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSDictionary *notification = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    //notification is what you want. print it to find out the details. 
    //Title, Badge Count and all that
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I need little more help. Inside 'application didReceiveRemoteNotification', I have to set: badge No. = existing badge No. + 1. And, how to find this existing badge No.?

Comment: I'm not so sure, but I think it set the `Badge Number` automatically when receive a APN. Maybe save the number in the `NSUserDefault` when receive a APN and then read it when received another.?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit accurate for what you are looking for

Do this in `appdelegate.m` ---> in `didfinishlaunching` method :

```
NSString *badgeCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]];
NSInteger countNumber = [badgeCount intValue];
```

Or if you want to set 0 initially:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
//this will set 0 to initial badge no
```